# OpenCV2.4.10 with iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, bitcode

ld: '/Users/zq/Desktop/code/practise/OpenCVTestP1/OpenCVTestP1/3rdLib/opencv2.framework/opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Build Settings in Xcode and type a search for "Bitcode" - you can then see where to enable or disable it as required.